# To read alphanumeric number last digit in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

i have  Alphanumeric numbers Ex `DLCSSZ51009328` and `HAMATM5100036V`

I want to check the last digit is number or Alphabet

i want excel formula to do below work

- IF(Right(A1,1) not equal to any Alphabet (i mean A to Z), "xyz","mastan")

or

- IF(Right(A1,1)=any number,"xyz","mastan")

what should we take for last digit Not equal to any Alphabet(from A to Z)?
what should we take for last digit equal to any number?

Comment: I want to check the last digit is number or Alphabet

Comment: `Right(A1, 1) Like "#"` = is a numeric character.  Do you want a formula, or VBA though?

Comment: Want Formula,if not then VBA code

Comment: Do a search on here, there is a q+a which is more than similar to what you want - it limits to A-Z and 0-9 excluding all special chars...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for an Excel formula for your answer, you could use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(A1,1)*1>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

It will evaluate TRUE if the last digit is a number, or
It will evaluate FALSE if the last digit is anything other than a number (a letter)

Please let me know if this does not work for your purpose.

---

Edit:

A simpler version of the above code, as pointed out by @Bathsheba in the comments:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,1)*1,FALSE)
```

It will evaluate to a number if the last digit is a number, or it will evaluate FALSE if the last digit is anything other than a number (a letter)

Comment: Will this class   : , @ , & , # as letters?

Comment: @MastanShaik although the above formula can be simplified (the inner IF is a tautology and can be removed), if you find this answer helpful you ought to accept it.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, those characters will evaluate FALSE. It should work for the purpose OP required it for.

Comment: @Bathsheba the inner IF is only included for ease of reading the result, but you are right, it is not necessary.

Comment: I’d upvote if you submit the smaller alternative, even if you retain your mode readable (?) version.

Comment: Here it comes !

Comment: @Bathsheba '=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,1)*1,FALSE)' formula working fine,when its true it giving last digit(number),But what i want is,If it is a number,result will be 'yes' and for False its 'no'.is it possible?

Comment: @Mastan Shaik '=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(A1,1)*1>0,"Yes","No"),"No")'